# Prove a particular matrix is invertible with high probability as the field size goes to infinity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I'm working with a square matrix $A$ that has $(2r-1)m$ rows with $m$ being an even number. Among all rows of $A$, there are $m$ rows that contain only randomly generated non-zero elements. The other $(2r-2)m$ rows contain half non-zero elements where each half-zero row has a compliment row with the position of the zero and non-zero elements swapped. All non-zero elements are randomly generated.

Now I want to show that the matrix $A$ is invertible with high probability as the field size (in which the random elements are generated) goes to infinity.

I can re-arranging the rows of $A$ to make all elements along the diagonal are non-zero. But what's the next step? Maybe the Schwartz-Zippel Lemma is useful when proving the determinant of $A$ is non-zero. Can anyone help me?

Comment: how much algebra are you comfortable with?  This is probably best answered in terms of $A\in R^{d\times d}$ with $R:= \mathbb Z\big[\mathbf x\big]$ then using substitution homomorphisms and finishing with Schwartz-Zippel.  Also, to be clear the 'randomly generated elements' are i.i.d., uniformly at random from $\mathbb K-\big\{0\big\}$, correct?

Comment: Yes. Could you explain or give me some reference on the substitution homomorphisms and how is it used? Thanks.

Comment: Put differently are you comfortable with the basics of commutative rings?  The "Rings" chapter in Artin's *Algebra* (1st edition in particular) is what I tacitly have in mind.  (While not technically necessary, some of the intuition comes 2 chapters later in the Modules chapter.) Basically the substitution homormorphism is an evaluation map (10.3.3, 10.3.4) that allows you to see send e.g. $x_i \mapsto \alpha \in \mathbb K$.